# My SQL group_concat sorting the concatenated column correct but not the rest of the columns?

Tags: mysql, sql, sql-order-by, group-concat

I have a mysql question that I thought wouldn't be a question. I am trying to group concat by one column, but then pretty much keep the rest of the columns in the same order. For example, my output for the 3rd listing is "9Lives......." The overline is sorting how I want it to, by "popular" in descending order. How do i make the rest of the columns sort in the same way so that the "itemupc" matches with the overline information??

Here is the code:

```sql
select group_concat( distinct overline order by popular desc) as 'overline' ,item, itemupc,popular
from shelftalkers
group by item,size;
```

[image: sql code with output]

Comment: You want to order by popular in desc order ?
what is your sql_mode ??

Comment: Yes i want to have the whole table to be sorted in the same order, so that the UPC number matches the first item that shows up on my overline. I am using STRICT_TRANS_TABLES,NO_ENGINE_SUBSTITUTION

Comment: I can't figure out what you want.  Desired results would help.  What does `group by` have to do with sorting?

Comment: select group_concat( distinct overline order by popular desc) as 'overline' ,item, itemupc,popular
from shelftalkers
group by item,size
order by popular desc;

is this what you want ?

Comment: Sorry guys. So i have a table with thousands of sale items. So I am grouping all of the items that have the same "Item" description and the same "size". So all of the "9Lives Wet Cat Food" that are "24 ounce packages" should be in one row. The group_concat is so that I get all of the different varieties of Cat Food to be in the "overline" column. 9Lives has 20 different cat food varieties: "Chicken Dinner", Beef", Salmon, etc.. I also have the most popular items coded with an "x" in the "popular" column (order by..)The itemupc column SHOULD be the unique UPC of the first item in the overline.

Comment: Amir Saleem, your suggestion is not ordering the rest of the columns in the same order as how the group_concat column is ordering, therefore, the itemupc is not matching the first item in the group_concat column... but thanks for trying!

Comment: @AmirSaleem didn't tag you above ^^^ =)

Answer (score 0):

**This seems to have done the trick!**

select itemupc, itemno,itemdesc, 
group_concat(overline  SEPARATOR ', ') as 'overline', 
item, saleprice,size,unitprice,popular,catdesc,rtcomm,
picture1,picture2,originalsort

from

(select * from shelftalkers 
group by popular,item,size,overline, saleprice
order by item, size,popular desc 
)

shelftalkers

group by  item,size, saleprice
order by item, size;

This gets me the output that I was looking for!